# How can pressure effect the melting/freezing point ("microscopic" side of view)?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, phase-transition, molecules

how can we explain the effect of pressure on the melting/freezing point from **microscopic** side of view? I mean how can we explain it with the manner of molecules and atoms **not how we see it Macroscopic**?

Comment: Throw a PV term into the GIbbs free energy and see!

Comment: entire books have been written about this. Please research *phase diagrams* and then come back here if you need any help with the concepts.